# Uploading Business Central Base App.xlf results in “Failed to extract the contents of the uploaded file.”

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, microsoft-translator, dynamics-business-central

I try to upload the System App.xlf file from English into German (by Business Central 18), but everytime I upload the file, I receive an error that says "Failed to extract the contents of the uploaded file." after 2-3 minutes. Both files are written in xliff version 1.2.

I can't figure out, why file is not processed. Some more information would be useful. Is this error thrown cause of special character?

Comment: Please email custommt@microsoft.com with the deals of your project

Answer (score 0):

The Base Application could have some missing -tags in the -tags, which leads to the error. You can use an xlst-File to delete tags with missing. This will delete the -tags with an empty -tag too.